# Apply function on cumulative values of pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an equivalent of `rolling_apply` in pandas that applies function to the cumulative values of a series rather than the rolling values?  I realize `cumsum`, `cumprod`, `cummax`, and `cummin` exist, but I'd like to apply a custom function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`pd.expanding_apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html#expanding-window-moment-functions). Below is a simple example which only really does a cumulative sum, but you could write whatever function you wanted for it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[10*i for i in range(0,10)]})

def sum_(x):
    return sum(x)


df['example'] = pd.expanding_apply(df['data'], sum_)

print(df)

#   data  example
#0     0        0
#1    10       10
#2    20       30
#3    30       60
#4    40      100
#5    50      150
#6    60      210
#7    70      280
#8    80      360
#9    90      450
```

Comment: In new pandas >= 0.18.0 it is replaced by DataFrame.expanding().apply()

Comment: New documentation link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.apply.html

Answer (score 1):

[Follow up to @Ffisegydd's answer]

Update for pandas == 1.0.5

```
df['example'] = df['data'].expanding().apply(sum_)
```