# Pandas: cumulative functions application

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the simple `dataframe` example using `pandas`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [10, 20, 30, 40]}, index = ['0','1','2', '3'])
```

This gives the following:

```
index x
0     10
1     20
2     30
3     40
```

I'm trying to take values of `x` and for each row produce a result (via a `lambda`) that also utilises the previous row calculation. That is, I'd like to calculate `y[i+1]` as a function of `x[i+1]` and `y[i]`. So for example:

```
y[i+1] = sin(x[i+1]) + (15 * y[i])
```

So this would give the following `DataFrame`:

```
index x  y
0     10 -0.54
1     20 -7.2
2     30 -109.7
3     40 -1644.7
```

For the first row, this is presumably a special case (as there is no `y[-1]`)? So I'd like to give this a specific number.

I have been trying to solve this with `expanding_apply`, but with no joy. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

So I answered my question, in a way I understand, with the help below (thank you):

```
df.loc[:,'y'] = 0
initial_y_val = 10

for i in range (0, df.shape[0]):
    if i == 0 : df.iloc[0,1] = initial_y_val + df.iloc[0,0] 
    else      : df.iloc[i,1] = df.iloc[i,0] + df.iloc[(i-1),1] 

print df
```

This gives:

```
    x    y
0  10   20
1  20   40
2  30   70
3  40  110
```

So my question is, is there a more idiomatic (and faster) way of achieving the same outcome?

Comment: Look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033198/apply-function-on-cumulative-values-of-pandas-series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `cumsum` from `pandas` which solves your problem:

```
df['y'] = df.x.cumsum()

In [171]: df
Out[171]:
    x    y
0  10   10
1  20   30
2  30   60
3  40  100
```

Edit:

Very nice question indeed, you can see by developping `y1, y2, ...,yn` that it's a growing polynomial of `sin(x)` with coefficient which are power of `15`. I would opt for this solution by iterating over the `DataFrame` index:

```
z = df.x.map(math.sin)

df['y']=[sum(z[:i]*15**np.arange(int(i)+1)[::-1]) for i,r in df.iterrows()]

In [258]: df
Out[258]:
    x            y
0  10    -0.544021
1  20    -7.247371
2  30  -109.698603
3  40 -1644.733929
```

Comment: Thanks. Ideally I'd like to add a `lambda` in the `cumsum`. So to get to `y` I take `x` and apply some function.

Comment: what do you want to do that whereas you have a simple existing solution?

Comment: Good question @ColonelBeauvel - I don't think my question was clear enough. So I've made an edit which hopefully makes things clearer...

Comment: That's great. Thanks. How would this work if the index was of type `DateTime`?