# Apply custom cumulative function to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe sorted by `date`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'date': ['2016-04-30', '2016-05-31', '2016-06-31',
                            '2016-04-30', '2016-05-31', '2016-06-31'],
                   'val': [10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 0],
                   'pct_val': [None, -10, None, None, -10, -10]})
df = df.sort('date')
print df

         date  idx  pct_val  val
3  2016-04-30    2      NaN   10
0  2016-04-30    1      NaN   10
4  2016-05-31    2      -10    0
1  2016-05-31    1      -10    0
5  2016-06-31    2      -10    0
2  2016-06-31    1      NaN    5
```

And I want to group by `idx` then apply a cumulative function with some simple logic.  If `pct_val` is null, add `val` to to running total, otherwise multiply running total by `1 + pct_val/100`.  `'cumsum'` shows the result of `df.groupby('idx').val.cumsum()` and `'cumulative_func'` is the result I want.

```
         date  idx  pct_val  val  cumsum  cumulative_func
3  2016-04-30    2      NaN   10      10               10
0  2016-04-30    1      NaN   10      10               10
4  2016-05-31    2      -10    0      10                9
1  2016-05-31    1      -10    0      10                9
5  2016-06-31    2      -10    0      10                8
2  2016-06-31    1      NaN    5      15               14
```

Any idea if there is a way to do apply a custom cumulative function to a dataframe or a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `pct_change()` function or the `shift()`?  You would most likely need a method that you pass the dataframe to do the logic and return the result.  You could use the `apply()` to do calculations on individual columns.

Comment: Can you update your code above so we can easily create the df? Also, your pct_val is "-10" but it looks like you really want to multiply by pct_val/100.0

Comment: I see you edited, but it's important that you divide by 100.0, and not 100.  Dividing by 100 will do integer math (-10/100), which will be 0 ( an integer, not a float)

Comment: @flyingmeatball Good point, but that part is pseudo-code anyway, just to explain the logic.

Comment: On how to apply a custom cumulative function to a dataframe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033198/apply-function-on-cumulative-values-of-pandas-series

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the update @luca

Comment: Similar question: [Vectorize a folding process in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78015392/vectorize-a-folding-process-in-a-dataframe). The answers over there suggest using numba+numpy for a fast calculation, or itertools.accumulate for a very simple very readable code (but slower than numba)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there is an easy way to accomplish your objective using vectorization.  I would first try to get something working, and then optimize for speed if required.

```
def cumulative_func(df):
    results = []
    for group in df.groupby('idx').groups.itervalues():
        total = 0
        result = []
        for p, v in df.ix[group, ['pct_val', 'val']].values:
            if np.isnan(p):
                total += v
            else:
                total *= (1 + .01 * p)
            result.append(total)
        results.append(pd.Series(result, index=group))
    return pd.concat(results).reindex(df.index)

df['cumulative_func'] = cumulative_func(df)

>>> df
         date  idx  pct_val  val  cumulative_func
3  2016-04-30    2      NaN   10             10.0
0  2016-04-30    1      NaN   10             10.0
4  2016-05-31    2      -10    0              9.0
1  2016-05-31    1      -10    0              9.0
5  2016-06-31    2      -10    0              8.1
2  2016-06-31    1      NaN    5             14.0
```

Comment: Beat me to it - I agree there won't be a good vectorized way to do this.  If you want to maybe improve speed slightly you can send data for each group to a numpy array - itervalues() is always really really slow.

Comment: `itervalues()` is on a dictionary, so I don't think it will be slow.  `groups = {1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [3, 4, 5]}`

Comment: True - I read your script quickly, you're already avoiding the .iterrows() construct  by using itervalues() on the dict., so +1 for speed!

Answer (score 1):

First I cleaned up your setup

## Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'date': ['2016-04-30', '2016-05-31', '2016-06-31',
                            '2016-04-30', '2016-05-31', '2016-06-31'],
                   'val': [10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 0],
                   'pct_val': [None, -10, None, None, -10, -10]})
df = df.sort_values(['date', 'idx'])
print df
```

Looks like:

```
         date  idx  pct_val  val
0  2016-04-30    1      NaN   10
3  2016-04-30    2      NaN   10
1  2016-05-31    1    -10.0    0
4  2016-05-31    2    -10.0    0
2  2016-06-31    1      NaN    5
5  2016-06-31    2    -10.0    0
```

## Solution

```
def cumcustom(df):
    df = df.copy()
    running_total = 0
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if pd.isnull(row.ix['pct_val']):
            running_total += row.ix['val']
        else:
            running_total *= row.ix['pct_val'] / 100. + 1
        df.loc[idx, 'cumcustom'] = running_total
    return df
```

Then apply

```
df.groupby('idx').apply(cumcustom).reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(['date', 'idx'])
```

Looks like:

```
         date  idx  pct_val  val  cumcustom
0  2016-04-30    1      NaN   10       10.0
3  2016-04-30    2      NaN   10       10.0
1  2016-05-31    1    -10.0    0        9.0
4  2016-05-31    2    -10.0    0        9.0
2  2016-06-31    1      NaN    5       14.0
5  2016-06-31    2    -10.0    0        8.1
```