# Calculation of multiplicative percentages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, percentage

I am trying to calculate percent of percent. per, per1, and per1-per are in percentages

```
date      per    per1   per1-per
1/1/2021   0      0        0
2/1/2021   0      0        0
3/1/2021   2      3        1
4/1/2021   0      2        2
5/1/2021   5      1       -4
6/1/2021   0      0        0
```

my desired output would be

```
date      per    per1   per1-per  per_of_per
1/1/2021   0      0        0          0
2/1/2021   0      0        0          0
3/1/2021   2      3        1          1 
4/1/2021   0      2        2          3.02
5/1/2021   5      1       -4         -1.10
6/1/2021   0      0        0         -1.10
```

How per_of_per is calculated is:

- for first time,  `per_of_per[0] = (1+per1-per[0])-1`
- for second time, `per_of_per[1] = (1+per1-per[0])*(1+per1-per[1])-1`
- for third time,  `per_of_per[2] = (1+per1-per[0])*(1+per1-per[1])*(1+per1-per[2])-1`
  and so on..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply custom cumulative function to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284083/apply-custom-cumulative-function-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No actually, it does the sum whereas I want to multiply instead of sum

Comment: Check the link again. It's not about cumsum, it's about making  your own cumulative function. Just like you want

Comment: Are you sure of the provided output?

Comment: @mozway, Yes I edited my first df. Now, I am sure of output

Comment: @AmitKumar makes sense now, you can use `cumprod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) after converting percent to int, adding 1, then perform the reverse process to give back percent:

```
df['pre_per'] = df['per1-per'].div(100).add(1).cumprod().sub(1).mul(100)
```

output:

```
       date  per  per1  per1-per  pre_per
0  1/1/2021    0     0         0   0.0000
1  2/1/2021    0     0         0   0.0000
2  3/1/2021    2     3         1   1.0000
3  4/1/2021    0     2         2   3.0200
4  5/1/2021    5     1        -4  -1.1008
5  6/1/2021    0     0         0  -1.1008
```