# Vectorize a folding process in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

Suppose we have a sample dataframe like the one below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
                   'B': [np.nan, 3, 4, 1, 2], 
                   'C': [10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
>>> df
     A    B     C
0  NaN  NaN  10.0
1  0.5  3.0   NaN
2  0.5  4.0   NaN
3  0.5  1.0   NaN
4  0.5  2.0   NaN
```

Col 'D' is calculated with the following operation:

```
>>> df
     A    B     C     D
0  NaN  NaN  10.0  10.0 
1  0.5  3.0   NaN   8.0 = (10 x 0.5) + 3
2  0.5  4.0   NaN   8.0 = (8 x 0.5) + 4 
3  0.5  1.0   NaN   5.0 = (8 x 0.5) + 1 
4  0.5  2.0   NaN   4.5 = (5 x 0.5) + 2
```

Calculating col 'D' reflects a folding process that recalls the previous row of col 'C' and current row of col 'A' and 'B' in each row operation.

I've tried using for loops, functools.reduce() and iterators to do this, but I want to know if there's another method that uses vectorization as much as possible in order to make this operation more efficient in a larger dataset.

Comment: Will column A always contain only `0.5`? If not, I think @Andrej Kesely's answer is the best way to go

Comment: It doesn't have to

Comment: Similar question: [Apply custom cumulative function to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284083/apply-custom-cumulative-function-to-pandas-dataframe) (I didn't flag as duplicate because your question is better-worded and has better answers, in my opinion)

Comment: There is also this answer toanother similar question [Apply function on cumulative values of pandas series?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033268/3080723) which suggests using [Expanding.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.apply.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of pure vectorized pandas/numpy solution, but you can try to use [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) to speed up the computation:

```py
from numba import njit


@njit
def calculate(A, B, starting_value=10):
    out = np.empty_like(A, dtype=np.float64)

    out[0] = starting_value

    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(A[1:], B[1:]), 1):
        out[i] = (out[i - 1] * a) + b

    return out


df["D"] = calculate(df["A"].values, df["B"].values, 10)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     A    B     C     D
0  NaN  NaN  10.0  10.0
1  0.5  3.0   NaN   8.0
2  0.5  4.0   NaN   8.0
3  0.5  1.0   NaN   5.0
4  0.5  2.0   NaN   4.5
```

Comment: Thanks for showing a clean example using numba and numpy matrices! This seems to be the fastest method I've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fun result. You can write this in numpy using `cumprod` and `convolve` but it is ~300x slower than the numba version above. If you replace the convolution by one of `convolve, fftconvolve, oaconvolve` from scipy.signal you can get it to be just ~7x slower in my tests with `10**4` random rows. I suspect this would be even worse with bigger inputs since the computational complexity of the convolution is in `O(n log(n))` while the direct implementation has linear complexity. Here is the code:

```
factors = np.array([1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
summands = np.array([10, 3., 4., 1., 2.])
np.convolve(np.cumprod(factors), summands)[:len(factors)]
```

Comment: To be fair, it takes a really huge n to make a distinction between O(n log(n)) and O(n). For instance, log2(4 billions) is only 32.

Comment: @stef well there are multiple reasons why the following is not strictly correct BUT for a gut feeling I would  look at the logarithm laws and translate it to: for the complexity to go up by a factor of two I have to square the input size since log(n^2)=2*log(n). I.e. Since my horrible algorithm took 6x longer for 10^4 examples I expect it to very ruffly take 12x longer on 10^8 examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can do your task using *itertools.accumulate*.

Start from `from itertools import accumulate`.

Then define the following function:

```
def myFun(prev, a):
    return prev * a[0] + a[1]
```

And call it the following way:

```
df['D'] = list(accumulate(df.values[1:, :2], myFun, initial = df.loc[0, 'C']))
```

The result is:

```
     A    B     C     D
0  NaN  NaN  10.0  10.0
1  0.5  3.0   NaN   8.0
2  0.5  4.0   NaN   8.0
3  0.5  1.0   NaN   5.0
4  0.5  2.0   NaN   4.5
```

Comment: Thanks for showing a cool way to use itertools.accumulate. I've tested the code with 100 million rows of some random integers, but it seems to be slower than using numpy matrices and for loops...