# pandas, rolling function dependent on all previous calculations

Tags: python, pandas, smoothing, rolling-computation

```
def apply_filter(values: List, alpha: float) -> List:
    prev_filtered_value = 0
    filtered_values = []
    for i in range(len(values)):
        filtered_value = ((1 - alpha) * values[i]) + (alpha * prev_filtered_value)
        filtered_values.append(filtered_value)
        prev_filtered_value = filtered_value

    return filtered_values
```

How can I do similar calculation in pandas not having to run for-loop? Each calculation depends on previous computed as well as current value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function on cumulative values of pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033198/apply-function-on-cumulative-values-of-pandas-series)

Comment: @G.Anderson the main issue here is that current value is dependent on calculation of all the previous values. Say alpha is 0.95 then we need 0.05 * current_value + (.95 * previous_value) and previous value depends on its predecessor ...

Comment: Which is the use-case of the linked duplicate; applying cumulative functions _is_ "current value is dependent on calculation of all the previous values". Have you attempted the solution in that question/answers?

Comment: Couldn't figure out how i can apply a function that needs both the current row and previous row as argument.

Comment: I got the same result with,
ewm(alpha=0.02, adjust=False).mean()